# How to create an NxN array JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a 2D array, like below, when given an integer n, I am using nested for loops and I can create the array but for some reason I can't figure out how to fill it with 1 to (n *n). Any suggestions?

`1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9`

Comment: Just creating an example for you

Answer (score 0):

```js
let n = 3, i, j;
let a = [];
for (i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    a[i] = [];
    for (j = 0; j < n; j ++) {
        a[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below is a basic solution. It helps to visualise the problem before solving it. You start at the first row, on the first column. You only want to change rows once the column has been filled with all values. The outer for loop controls the rows, and the inner for loop controls the columns.

```js
var n = 3;
var counter  = 1;
var outerArray = [];

// Now just add to the array with a nested for loop
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // Add empty array to the outer array.
    outerArray.push([]);
    // outer for loop steps through the rows
    for(var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        // The inner loop steps through the columns
        outerArray[i][j] = counter;
        counter++;
    }
  }
// Now just print the array.
console.log(outerArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function printTable(n) {
 let i, j;
let a = [];
let counter = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    a[i] = [];
    for (j = 0; j < n; j ++) {
   counter++
        a[i][j] = counter;
    }
}
console.log(a);
}
printTable(4)
```

Thanks guys! Modified it and figured it out

Comment: Awesome :) Good job.

Comment: Also, just so you know, you would have gotten down votes on your question because you did not show your attempt in the question.